# Why does rspec-puppet not find my class?

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

I've created a Puppet module to install AWS Cloudwatch monitoring scripts and set them up. The Puppet module is available [here](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/puppet-cloudwatch).

When I run `rake spec`, my test suite fails with:

```
rspec ./spec/classes/init_spec.rb:4 # cloudwatch with default values for all parameters should contain Class[cloudwatch]
```

I cannot for the life of me work out why this test is failing. How do I fix it?

I've tried creating a `.fixtures/yml` in the root of the repo with the following content:

```
fixtures:
  symlinks:
    cloudwatch: "../../../../manifests"

fixtures:
  symlinks:
    cloudwatch: "#{source_dir}"
```

But no dice.

I've also tried using a symlink to link to the manifests directory: https://github.com/MasterRoot24/puppet-cloudwatch/commit/932970aab085984f2cda44fba841c3bde20f7a2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial problem is you're missing the `.fixtures.yml` file, which needs the following content:

```
fixtures:
  symlinks:
    cloudwatch: "#{source_dir}"
```

as documented in the [puppetlabs_spec_helper README](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper).

Additional changes were required to get the test to pass as can be seen in the PR I just raised [here](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/puppet-cloudwatch/pull/3/files).

Responding to your edited question, which discusses a fixtures file that wasn't in the code you linked, I don't think your fixtures is syntactically valid; I don't believe you can specify more than one `fixtures` block.  Anyway, have a look at my PR.

Comment: He could also use puppet-check, which does this automatically and is being introduced at major companies and used by power users as a replacement for puppetlabs_spec_helper. Disclosure: I am the author.

Comment: It was my understanding that this was satisfied by the symlink here: https://github.com/MasterRoot24/puppet-cloudwatch/blob/develop/spec/fixtures/modules/cloudwatch/manifests Am I wrong? Is the code snippet ready to be copied verbatim, or do I need to change `source_dir` to something?

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work - please see the update at the end of my question

Comment: @MasterRoot24  I actually tested your code, so apparently your symlink didn't work.  I'll send in a pull request.

Comment: I just raised a PR after fixing the tests.  A few other changes were also required.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Thanks for the PR, I've just got round to looking at it and it all seems to make sense. Thanks for your help!